# What processes are using which ports on unix?

Tags: hp-ux

I need to find out what ports are attached to which processes on a Unix machine (HP Itanium). Unfortunately, `lsof` is not installed and I have no way of installing it.

Does anyone know an alternative method? A fairly lengthy Googling session hasn't turned up anything.

Comment: this depend of the unix used. what is it ?

Comment: Similar, in Unix & Linux: [What is using this network socket?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17/13260) (2010-08-10)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming this is HP-UX? What about the [Ptools](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/STK/HPUX_STK/impacts/i983.html) - do you have those installed? If so you can use "pfiles" to find the ports in use by the application:

> *pfiles prints information about all open file descriptors of a process.
>   If file descriptor corresponds to a file, then pfiles prints the fstat(2) 
>   and fcntl(2) information.*
>
> *If the file descriptor corresponds to a socket, then pfiles prints socket 
>   related info, such as the socket type, socket family, and protocol family.*
>
> *In the case of AF_INET and AF_INET6 family of sockets, information about 
>   the peer host is also printed.*

for f in $(ps -ex | awk '{print $1}'); do echo $f; pfiles $f | grep PORTNUM; done

switch PORTNUM for the port number. :)  may be child pid, but gets you close enough to identify the problem app.

Answer (score 44):

[netstat -l](http://www.faqs.org/docs/linux_network/x-087-2-iface.netstat.html) (assuming it comes with that version of UNIX)

Answer (score 28):

Given (almost) everything on unix is a file, and lsof lists open files...

Linux : `netstat -putan or lsof | grep TCP`

OSX : `lsof | grep TCP`

Other Unixen : `lsof` way...

Answer (score 13):

```
netstat -pln
```

EDIT: linux only, on other UNIXes netstat may not support all these options.

Answer (score 6):

```
netstat -ln | awk '/^(tcp|udp)/ { split($4, a, /:/); print $1, a[2]}' | sort -u
```

gives you the active tcp/udp ports. Then you can use the ports with `fuser -n tcp` or `fuser -n udp`, as root, and supposing that `fuser` is GNU fuser or has similar options.

If you need more help, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I use this command:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

You can have a clean output that shows process id and ports that's listening on

Comment: was going to answer the same, thanks that you've already posted this :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `pfiles PID` to show all open files for a process.

Answer (score 1):

Which process uses port in unix;

### 1. netstat -Aan | grep port

> root> netstat -Aan | grep 3872
>
> output> f1000e000bb5c3b8 tcp        0      0  *.3872   *.*                 LISTEN

### 2. rmsock f1000e000bb5c3b8 tcpcb

> output> The socket 0xf1000e000bb5c008 is being held by proccess 13959354 (java).

### 3. ps -ef | grep 13959354

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know **all listening ports along with its details**: local address, foreign address and state as well as Process ID (PID). You can use following command for it in linux.

```
 netstat -tulpn
```