# How to find out which Node.js pid is running on which port

Tags: node.js, port, kill, pid

I'd like to restart one of many Node.js processes I have running on my server. If I run `ps ax | grep node` I get a list of all my Node proccesses but it doesn't tell me which port they're on. How do I kill the one running on port 3000 (for instance). What is a good way to manage multiple Node processes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What processes are using which ports on unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126002/what-processes-are-using-which-ports-on-unix)

Comment: @blu yes you're right. I didn't see that one there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you run:

```
$ netstat -anp 2> /dev/null | grep :3000
```

You should see something like:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5902/node
```

In this case the `5902` is the pid. You can use something like this to kill it:

```
netstat -anp 2> /dev/null | grep :3000 | awk '{ print $7 }' | cut -d'/' -f1 | xargs kill
```

Here is an alternative version using `egrep` which may be a little better because it searches specifically for the string 'node':

```
netstat -anp 2> /dev/null | grep :3000 | egrep -o "[0-9]+/node" | cut -d'/' -f1 | xargs kill
```

You can turn the above into a script or place the following in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
function smackdown () {
  netstat -anp 2> /dev/null |
  grep :$@ |
  egrep -o "[0-9]+/node" |
  cut -d'/' -f1 |
  xargs kill;
}
```

and now you can run:

```
$ smackdown 3000
```

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. :) I added an alternative (possibly safer) version of the command and a `.bashrc` function to the answer.

Comment: put the smackdown function in my bashrc but it just outputs `Usage:
  kill pid ...              Send SIGTERM to every process listed.
  kill signal pid ...       Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -s signal pid ...    Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -l                   List all signal names.
  kill -L                   List all signal names in a nice table.
  kill -l signal            Convert between signal numbers and names.`

Comment: Did the egrep version work for you on the command line? You can try debugging the .bashrc function just by removing commands from the bottom up (start by removing the xargs call) and seeing what gets printed. remember to `source ~/.bashrc` after each change.

Comment: A little addition: if you're running on a sensitive port like 80, you might need to add `sudo` before the command.

Comment: And also, you might to add the pipe `| uniq` at the end, because the line might repeat several times.

Answer (score 13):

This saved me a lot of time:

`pkill node`

Comment: :D :D @NaveedUlIslam

Comment: Although this does not answer the entire question precisely, practically I would only run one instance of node per server. Port number becomes irrelevant in that case.

Answer (score 7):

A one-liner is

```
lsof -n -i:5000 | grep LISTEN | awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq | xargs -r kill -9
```

You only need the sudo if you are killing a process your user didn't start.  If your user started the node process, you can probably kill it w/o sudo.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Why not a simple `fuser` based solution?

If you don't care about whether the process using port 3000 is node, it could be as simple as

```
fuser -k -n tcp 3000
```

If you wan't to be sure you don't kill other processes, you could go with something like

```
PID="$(fuser -n tcp 3000 2>/dev/null)" \
  test "node"="$(ps -p $PID -o comm=)" && kill $PID
```