# Stopping all node processes in a directory aside from one I'm just starting

Tags: node.js, unix, process, sublimetext2

I'm using sublime text 2's build systems to aid development of my mongodb + node.js server, which is really handy as it enables me to test my code without having to keep going back and to to the terminal. The downside is that it's very easy to absent-mindedly leave multiple node processes running in the background, which sometimes causes clashes when one of them is using a port I need in order to test another module.

Is there some way I can stop all node processes running within a given directory whenever I start a new process from that directory? A bash script or similar?

Comment: Do you want to stop all node processes in that directory, or do you want to stop all within a certain port range, or both? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129464/how-to-find-out-which-node-js-pid-is-running-on-which-port/) may be useful to start with.

Comment: The ones that cause the problems are the ones listening to a port (which I do a `lsof -i:portnum -t` followed by `kill` to stop) but I'd like to solve the underlying problem of orphan node processes in general

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
ps auxwwwe | egrep " [n]ode .+ PWD=$PWD" | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill
```

This does the following:

1. Uses `ps` to get the full path to your processes.
2. Searches for all processes started with the `node` command in the present working directory (you can modify this with an absolute path, another environment variable, etc.).
3. Finds the 2nd column: the pid (use `awk` or `nawk` depending on your system).
4. Runs `kill` on each pid.