# How to check which port is used in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When I run process

`npm run start`

After that I'd like to monitor which port is used.

Is there any command to monitor this?

Comment: What is `npm run start` actually executing? Often you see output on which port is being used, or it's configurable by setting the `PORT` env var.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out which Node.js pid is running on which port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129464/how-to-find-out-which-node-js-pid-is-running-on-which-port)

Answer (score 1):

You can run below command and check for all the ports running node

netstat -nptl |grep node